# Kickstart virtual console: No 'Shell prompt' at Alt-F2

Tags: redhat, kickstart, rhel6, scientific-linux

I am installing Scientific Linux 6.1 via kickstart, and I am trying to debug a problem.

According to [Tips and tricks for anaconda and kickstart](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/KickStart#line-43), I should have several virtual consoles available:

```
What the different terminals display

Alt-F1    The installation dialog when using text or cmdline
Alt-F2    A shell prompt
Alt-F3    The install log displaying messages from install program
Alt-F4    The system log displaying messages from kernel, etc.
Alt-F5    All other messages
Alt-F7    The installation dialog when using the graphical installer
```

The Virtual Consoles <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> & <kbd>F5</kbd> all work and show various logging information. However, the Virtual Console at <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> does not do anything.

I could really use access to the shell prompt (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>), however there is no Shell prompt available at the second virtual console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>). All I have is a blinking '`_`'.

Can I force <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> to show me a shell prompt?

Answer (score 5):

I have just tested an automated kickstart install (driven by [cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/)) and it works fine for me. All I had to do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (virt-manager has a menu for this). The only problem is that the shell is not avaialble right away, you have to wait for the installer to reach a certain stage.

Regarding debugging, you might find the [Anaconda logging](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Logging) page helpful.

Comment: Do you happen to know the line which cobbler passes to the kernel? I am not using cobbler, but suspect that's my problem.

Comment: It's actually koan that starts the virtual machine, but here it is: `method=nfs:myserver:/Scientific-6.1-i386-DVD/ ks=http://myserver/cblr/svc/op/ks/system/myvm ksdevice=link kssendmac lang= text`

Comment: Are you installing Enterprise Linux version 5.7 (or similar) or version 6.x?

Comment: I've tested with Scientific Linux 6.1, the distribution mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look into /etc/inittab. Maybe the entry for tty2 is disabled. If you want a login prompt, put this line into it:

```
2:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
```

For an autokgin as root, use:

```
2:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin root --noclear tty2
```

After editing, make init re-read this config:

```
telinit q
```

You should see something on tty2 now.

Comment: This is an installer, not an installed system.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access a commandline to view those files. And as a sidenote, RHEL6 has replaced  /etc/inittab with Upstart (/etc/inittab is ignored).

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: Ok, the blank tty2 means that installation hasn't progressed so far that other vt's could be opened. What's in your ks.cfg? Any idea at what stage it fails?

Comment: @ott : I should clarify. The other Virtual Terminals (Alt-F1, F3, etc.) are working. Alt-F2 is the only VT which is *not* working. I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: Yes, the installation stops before it can start a shell on vt2, that's why you see nothing. I think you can't make "normal" screenshots, but could you take pictures of tty3 and tty4 to see the last steps?